# Impossible to apply changes after delete a table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to delete a table. I can only do it in the Power Query Editor but I can not apply the change when I exit it.

I have tried to delete from the view of report or of view of the model but I have the same error message following. I have changed the name of the table. The change is applied everywhere except in the part of "Fields"

[image]

the table is not used anywhere. I am not sure about the source, I think it's an import or direct query. 
I hope that you can help me,  I have been looking for a solution since some days :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to delete the table, you can directly do this from the Fields section. Hover over the Name of the table in the Fields section till the three dots appear and then click on the three dots (...). Then select delete, this should delete the table from the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I followed your advice and I have the same error message. Very strange ! Do you think the probleme could come from the setting of Power BI ?

Comment: Have you applied any language translation to the report?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have not been notified of your comment. I have not applied any language translation.
I just export the PIBX into a template. Then I have created a new one with the regional language in english( different than the other). After I migrate all object and item from the old template the new template. and since,  I can not delete this table. I tried everything